# Example of endomorphism $\phi$ such that $V \neq Im(\phi) \oplus Ker(\phi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Example of endomorphism  $\phi$ such that $V \neq Im(\phi) \oplus Ker(\phi)$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Is it possible to get one as I was thinking the basis to basis map, I calculated $V=\Bbb R^2$ so $\phi(x,y)=(x+y,0)$ then I realized that $ Im(\phi)=Sp\{(1,0)\}$ and $ Ker(\phi)=Sp\{(0,1)\}$. So it will not work.

Then I became confused remembering the proof of Rank-Nullity theorem. So is it possible to get one in finite dimensional space. Might not be!

I know for projection $\pi:V \to V$ $V=Im(\pi) \oplus Ker(\pi)$. What about others?

Comment: $\phi(x,y)=(0,x)$, the image is the same as the kernel.

Comment: How do you find that so quickly?!! :(

Comment: I don't know if this is how @GerryMyerson thought of it, but if $\phi^2 = 0$ and such a decomposition of $V$ is possible, then $Im(\phi) = 0$, which in turn implies $Ker(\phi) = V$, from which we deduce $\phi = 0$. Thus, if such a decomposition of $V$ is always possible, there is no endomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi^2 = 0$ and $\phi \neq 0$. On the other hand, the commenter just exhibited $\phi \neq 0$ such that $\phi^2 = 0$. Therefore such a decomposition of $V$ is not always possible.

Comment: Alternatively, $\phi^2 = 0$ if and only if $Im(\phi) \subset Ker(\phi)$, which means the only endomorphism with $\phi^2 = 0$ which admits such a decomposition of $V$ is $\phi = 0$.

Comment: More informally, nilpotent and idempotent operators usually make for good counterexamples.

Comment: I've been teaching Linear Algebra for 40 years, Shadow. You get to know things that way.

Comment: Speechless........